# Align controls side by side

Tags: css, css-float, stylesheet

I have to display three dropdowns next to the date field for hour/minutes/am pm.
How can I align all the four controls (including the date) horizontally side by side?

I tried wrapping them into a div and using float:left but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ppTPE/

Comment: Could you please show us the code your using? Preferably setup an example of jsfiddle :)

Comment: updated the Q with the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/ppTPE/1/

Try this:

**HTML**:

```
    <div>
    <input type="text" class="align">
    <ol class="align">
        <li class="align">
            <select name="hour" class="text">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li class="align">
            <select name="minute" class="text">
                <option value="0">00</option>
                <option value="5">05</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="35">35</option>
                <option value="40">40</option>
                <option value="45">45</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="55">55</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li class="align">
            <select name="ampm" class="text">
                <option value="0">AM</option>
                <option value="12">PM</option>
            </select>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <br />
    <div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.align {
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:top; 
}
```